# rm: cannot lstat directory, it says 'Invalid argument'

Tags: linux

We use a flash card on our MySQL server. After a reboot, there is a dead directory entry in the flash card mount; `rm -rf export-20130413-013547` returns the error `rm: cannot lstat 'export-20130413-013547': Invalid argument`.

Below is my `ls -lrt` output.

```
?--------- ? ?    ?         ?            ? export-20130413-013547
drwx------ 2 root root 143360 Apr 13 17:10 export-20130413-154729
```

Plus, when I want to see its inode by `ls -i`, the directory's inode is 0.

```
0 export-20130413-013547
```

Comment: did you try `fsck`?

Answer (score 1):

This is an orphaned directory entry. I don't know what file system the flash card uses (is it vfat?), but `fsck` may help, as may just unlinking it without bothering with stat - `rm -rf` will first try to figure out whether you're seleting a directory, and even a normal `rm` will try to do clever things. `/usr/bin/unlink export-20130413-013547` (part of coreutils) will do that for you.

Comment: unlink seems that doesn't work with directories. How can you unlink them?

Comment: If what you have is a directory, then your question is not the same as this question. Please ask a new question.

Comment: Did I missed something? The title says: `cannot lstat directory`, the  OP stated: `there is a dead directory entry...` , and in your answer contains: `This is an orphaned directory...`, however part of the solution you posted only works on files (`unlink ****`). Anyway, I solved my problem running a full fsck as you suggested. Thanks.